# Can a java thread waiting with wait() ,notify itself?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I came across the following e example to implement custom suspend and wait from some website.

```
  // Suspending and resuming a thread the modern way.
 class NewThread implements Runnable {
     String name; // name of thread
     Thread t;
     boolean suspendFlag;
     NewThread(String threadname) {
         name = threadname;
         t = new Thread(this, name);
         System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
         suspendFlag = false;
         t.start(); // Start the thread
     }
     // This is the entry point for thread.
     public void run() {
         try {
             for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
                 System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
                 Thread.sleep(200);
                 synchronized(this) {
                     while (suspendFlag) {
                         wait();
                     }
                 }
             }
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
         }
         System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
     }
     void mysuspend() {
         suspendFlag = true;
     }
     synchronized void myresume() {
         suspendFlag = false;
         notify();
     }
 }
 class SuspendResume {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
             NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
             NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);

                 ob1.mysuspend();

                 System.out.println("Suspending thread One");

                 Thread.sleep(1000);

                 ob1.myresume();
                 ...................
```

I am more concerned about the ob1.mysuspend() and ob1.myresume() calls. When my suspend is called then ob1 will be placed into the blocking queue associated with the runnable object it is using. When ob1 calls myresume, then how does it work as ob1 is already in waiting queue for the same object, can the waiting object enters another synchronised method and then signals notify to itself?How does this work?What am I missing?

Comment: The lock is released when the thread enters `wait()`, so other threads can acquire it.

Comment: Re, "When ob1 calls myresume,..." The only thread that ever calls `myresume()` in your program is the _main_ thread. Not sure what you mean by "ob1 calls...", but the `ob1.myresume()` statement in your program is executed by the main thread (i.e., by the same Java thread that calls your `main(...)` routine.) That call clears the `suspendFlag` that _belongs to_ the `ob1` object, and it `notify()`s the `ob1` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread is written so that while an instance of `NewThread` is running, another thread can call `mysuspend` to suspend that running thread. Again, a thread other than the suspended thread calls `myresume` to resume the suspended thread.

There also appears to be a data race because `mysuspend` writes to `suspendFlag` without any synchronization. That means, the thread that needs to be suspended may not see that write immediately. `mysuspend` must be declared `synchronized`, or `suspendFlag` must be volatile.

Comment: Which is another thread that is calling myresume?Is it ob1?So ob1 is one thread and thread inside ob1(ob1.t) is another thread?

Comment: You have three threads, not two. The `ob1`, `ob2`, and the `main` thread. Main thread is suspending/resuming `ob1`

Comment: understood. the statements in main fall under main thread and statements under run fall under Thread's statements.

Answer (score 3):

This code is flat out broken.

### Straight up broken: JMM violation

The `mysuspend` method (which should be named `mySuspend`, by the way) updates a field that is then read from another thread, and isn't synchronized. **This is an error** - and a really nasty one because **you cannot reliably test that it is an error**. The Java Memory Model (JMM) states that any write to a field may be observable *or not*, at the discretion of the JVM implementation, unless a so-called Happens-Before/Happens-After relationship is established (there are many ways to do it; usually you do so via synchronized, volatile, or some other concurrency tool built on these primitives, such as the latches and queues in the `java.util.concurrent` package).

You do not establish such a relationship here, meaning, that `suspendFlag = true` results in a schroedingers cat variable: The other thread that reads this field may read true or false, the JVM gets to decide what you see. Hence: A bug, and, untestable. **bad**. Any field that is read/written to by multiple threads needs to be written extremely carefully.

Mark that method synchronized, that's a good first step.

### Wait and Notify

You've got it flipped around: You **must** in fact hold the synchronized lock on x when you invoke wait on x (here, x is `this`).

To call `x.wait()` (you are calling `this.wait()`, effectively), you must first be in a `synchronized(x)` block. Once the wait 'goes through', the code releases the lock (other `synchronized(x)` blocks can run). To invoke `x.notify()` you must *also* hold that lock.

`wait` does not return until the lock is re-established.

In other words:

```
public void foo() {
    wait();
}
```

will fail at runtime. Try it. Guaranteed exception. In the mean time, this:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // code before wait
        wait();
        // code after wait
    }
}
```

is executed as if it is written like this:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // code before wait
        release_lock(this);
        this.wait();
        acquire_lock(this);
        // code after wait
    }
}
```

Where acquire_lock is guaranteed to actually take a while (because by definition whatever invoked `notify()` to wake you up is currently holding it! So wait is always a two-hit thing: You need to be both notified AND the lock needs to be reacquired before your code will continue). Except, of course, acquire_lock and release_lock don't exist, and unlike this hypothetical code, wait() is more atomic than that.